# iOS11 AUGraphInitialize Err-code 560557684

Tags: background, core-audio, ios11

With the application in the background on iOS 11,
Execution of `AUGraphInitialize ()` fails,

`Error code 560557684` is returned and audio can not be played.

`AUGraphInitialize ()` was successful on iOS 10 in the same situation.

Is this a bug in iOS 11?
Is there planning to fix apple in this case?

If it is not a bug,
With iOS 11 the application is in the background,
What kind of implementation should be done to make `AUGraphInitialize ()` succeed?

Please give me hints!

Describe the source of this error case below.

```
 AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    if (audioSession == nil) {
        LOGE("AVAudioSession : sharedInstance() error.");
    }

    NSError *audioSessionError = nil;
    BOOL ret = [audioSession setActive:NO error:&audioSessionError];
    if (ret == false) {
        LOGE("AVAudioSession : setActive() error. code = %d", (int)audioSessionError.code);
    }

    NSTimeInterval bufferDuration = 2048 / 44100;
    ret = [audioSession setPreferredIOBufferDuration:bufferDuration error:&audioSessionError];
    if (ret == false) {
        LOGE("AVAudioSession : setPreferredIOBufferDuration() error. code = %d", (int)audioSessionError.code);
    }

    ret = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                      error:&audioSessionError];
    if (ret == false) {
        LOGE("AVAudioSession : setCategory() error. code = %d", (int)audioSessionError.code);
    }

    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&audioSessionError];

    OSStatus err = NewAUGraph(&mGraph);
    if ( err != noErr ) {
        LOGE("AUGraph : NewAUGraph() error. code = %d", (int)err);
    }

    err = AUGraphOpen(mGraph);
    if ( err != noErr ) {
        LOGE("AUGraph : AUGraphOpen() error. code = %d", (int)err);
    }

    AudioComponentDescription output_desc;
    output_desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    output_desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    output_desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    output_desc.componentFlags = 0;
    output_desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

    AUNode outputNode;
    err = AUGraphAddNode(mGraph, &output_desc, &outputNode);
    if ( err != noErr ) {
        LOGE("AUGraph : AUGraphAddNode() error. code = %d", (int)err);
    }

    err = AUGraphNodeInfo(mGraph, outputNode, NULL, &mOutUnit);
    if ( err != noErr ) {
        LOGE("AUGraph : AUGraphNodeInfo() error. code = %d", (int)err);
    }

    AURenderCallbackStruct callback;
    callback.inputProc = _renderCallback;
    callback.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*)self;

    err = AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback(mGraph,
                                      outputNode,
                                      0,
                                      &callback);
    if ( err != noErr ) {
        LOGE("AUGraph : AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback() error. code = %d", (int)err);
    }

    AudioStreamBasicDescription outputFormat;
    UInt32 size = sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription);
    err = AudioUnitGetProperty( mOutUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &outputFormat, &size );
              if ( err != noErr ) {
        LOGE("AUGraph : AudioUnitGetProperty() error. code = %d", (int)err);
        return nil;
              }

    outputFormat.mSampleRate = 44100.0f;

    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(mOutUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &outputFormat, size);
    if ( err != noErr ) {
        LOGE("AUGraph : AudioUnitSetProperty() error. code = %d", (int)err);
    }

    err = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(mGraph,
                            outputNode, 0,
                            outputNode, 1
                            );
    if ( err != noErr ) {
        LOGE("AUGraph : AUGraphConnectNodeInput() error. code = %d", (int)err);
    }

    err = AUGraphInitialize(mGraph);
    if ( err != noErr ) {
        LOGE("AUGraph : AUGraphInitialize() error. code = %d", (int)err);
    }
```

Comment: It's quite possible that the error is the opposite of your hypothesis: that AUGraphInitialize worked from the background in the past might have been the bug, and it now works correctly by returning an "!int" error.

Comment: Works for me on iOS 11. 560557684 = !int = `AVAudioSessionErrorCodeCannotInterruptOthers`, look into @hotpaw2's suggestion about backgroundness/what other audio apps are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
A bug in iOS 10 or earlier may have been fixed,I understood that.

However, since I want to make the operation by the bug of iOS 10 the correct operation,Please tell me how to make it on iOS 11.

Comment: What I would like is the operation in the following below.

[Step 1]
Play music with my app,
The sound of my app is output from the iPhone.

[Step 2]
Play music with "Music" app,
The sound of "music" app is output from the iPhone.
In this case, the sound of my app in the background state should not be output.

[Step 3]
With my app dedicated to my app,Start playback in the background state,
The sound of my app is output from the iPhone.
At this time, the sound of "Music" app in the foreground state should not be output.

Comment: Please tell me how to realize what I want to do with iOS 11.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 are the normal behaviour for a playback audio session category. Starting playback from the background is not straightforward on iOS, it normally happens in response to some external event & might not actually be possible with a playback category (but I'd have to try it to be sure).

Comment: @tochi-suke Can you please check if there's an actual error being returned here? [audioSession setActive:YES error:&audioSessionError];

Comment: @kvr  i checked the behavior of [audioSession setActive]. and i got the same result as the main subject.
in case of OK: YES　audioSessionError=0
in case of NG: NO audioSessonErr=560557684(AVAudioSessionCodeCannotInterruptOthers)

its same result as AUGraphInitialize().

Comment: @tochi-suke if you're unable to start the audio session, then that sounds like a primary issue you need to solve before looking at audio graph errors.